# Recording the Android screen

Tags: android, recording

I want to write an game for Android. To present it very well, it has to have an YouTube movie in the Google Play Store.

How can I do this? Because ADB only produce a slideshow, because it's to slow. Is there an app for recording out there?

PS: I only have Tegra devices (Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 7), so http://pkg.to/com.ms.screencast doesn't work, yet.

Answer (score 0):

The new Android 4.2 has a wireless display feature allowing the send the screen's content to TV screens etc. As you have Nexus devices I guess you'll get the update very soon. I do not know the technical details but I'm quite sure there will be possibilities to record the sent signal.

See this anouncement: http://www.android.com/whatsnew/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using the emulator and record using a regular video recording program such as FRAPS. The performance of the x86 emulator has improved greatly and also supports GPU emulation.

Here is a page from the Android documentation outlining how to enable hardware acceleration for the emulator:

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration

The downside to this approach is that multi-touch gestures aren't easy to do.